# Translucent status bar in Android with Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin and I want to have transparent status bar in my application. I've read a lot of other threads here and on Xamarin forums but nothings helped me. The problems is instead of transparent status bar I got gray status bar.

Here is my source code: In `MainActivity.cs`

```java
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        LoadApplication(new App());


        var uiOptions = (int)Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility;
        uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.LayoutStable;
        uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.LayoutFullscreen;
        Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)uiOptions;

        Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.DrawsSystemBarBackgrounds);
        Window.SetStatusBarColor(Color.Transparent)  
    }
```

If tried setting different properties to the theme in styles.xml but nothing helped. Currently `styles.xml` is:

```xml
  <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
  </style>

  <style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item> 
    <item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item> 
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
  </style>
```

I'm testing on Android 5.1 (lollipop) so the transparent status bar should be supported. I even wrote simple native Android application to test if transparent is supported by my phone. I started with an application with blank activity, set a background image of the activity (to check if the status bar is transparent) and to MainActivity.java I wrote:

```java
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
    }
```

And I got transparent status bar. However, when I'm doing the same from Xamarin it doesn't work.

Comment: did you get this resolved? If you had working solution for this please post.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the following to your styles.xml inside values-v21 folder.

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Ah, didn't saw that you tried it by code already.

Answer (score 0):

Use below mentioned code. That has worked for me perfectly for Xamarin forms.

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
        {
            Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = 0;
            var statusBarHeightInfo = typeof(FormsAppCompatActivity).GetField("_statusBarHeight", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            statusBarHeightInfo.SetValue(this, 0);
            Window.SetStatusBarColor(new Android.Graphics.Color(18, 52, 86, 255));
        }

        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
}
```